# Как вывести данные в порядке обратном от того, в котором они лежат в БД?

Tags: sql, oracle

У меня есть поле поле `pipe_n`, в котором данные лежат так:

```
1
22
4
66
10
5
```

Мне нужно так:

```
5
10
66
4
22
1
```

Такое возможно?

Делаю отчет в mvc web form или может в программе такое возможно?
Данные записываются из программы тупо по очереди, исходника программы у меня нет, только БД с данными, и мне их нужно вывести в обратном порядке.
Поля ID в базе нет, а `group by` на это поле сортирует его по порядку, что мне не нужно.

Comment: Ну по какому-то же признаку у вас отсортированы записи в таблице, что значения поля pipe_n именно в таком порядке `5 10 66 4 22 1`.

Comment: Попадают из программы тупо по очереди, исходника программы у меня нет, только бд с данными, и мне их нужно вывести в обратном порядке

Comment: "Попадают из программы тупо по очереди" - вот и фиксируйте порядок записи исходя из этой очереди. Пока вы этого не сделаете ваша задача не решаема. Порядок считывания никоим образом не зависит от порядка записи. Псевдоколонака `rownum` в неуопорядоченном запросе получит случайные значения и пытаться упорядочить по ней конечный результат нет абсолютно никакого смысла.

Comment: `можете подсказать еще, я могу вывести как то номера полей по порядку из бд, ну тоесть где-то в селекте сделать поле типо номер, и что оно пронумеровало записи` Пожалуйста, старайтесь задавать вопросы ориентируясь на правило "одна тема - один топик". Ваш вопрос содержит (помимо основной части, вынесенной в заголовок) ещё совершенно другой вопрос, который стоит задать отдельно, а не смешивать с текущим.

Comment: ["Что делать с ответами на мой вопрос?"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 6):

TL;DR Порядок считывания строк из таблицы никоим образом не зависит от порядка, в котором эти строки были записаны, или другими словами - от порядка вставки.
Без явного указания сортировки с `order by`, порядок вывода строк произволен и может менятся от вызова к вызову одного и того же запроса.

---

Попробуем:

```sql
create table pipes (pipe_n number);

insert into pipes (pipe_n) 
    select column_value pipe_n
    from sys.ODCINumberList (1, 22, 4, 66, 10, 5)
;

select pipe_n
from pipes
order by rownum desc; 

    PIPE_N
----------
         5
        10
        66
         4
        22
         1
```

Работает? Вроде да, результат же достигнут. **Нет**, это иллюзия, это "бомба замедленного действия". Сколько она будет тикать - никто не знает, может месяц, год, два.

Ещё раз, порядок считывания строк из таблицы не зависит от порядка их записи и он произволен. То есть то, что значению, например,  `pipe_n=5` будет всегда присвоено `rownum=6` **не гарантируется**.

> Поля ID в базе нет

Создайте, это и будет лучшее решение:

```sql
rollback;
alter table pipes add order_of_ins number generated always as identity (nocache);
```

И после вставки приведённой выше, запрос:

```sql
select pipe_n
from pipes
order by order_of_ins desc;
```

Выведет желаемый результат как и выше, но он гарантирован и никогда не изменится.