# Сортируются даты ли даты по умолчанию без явного указания сортировки order by?

Tags: sql, oracle, сортировка

Подскажите пожалуйста, надо ли принудительно делать сортировку по дате или по умолчанию она всегда выводится в отсортированном виде? Вывожу в запросе только один столбец с датой.

```
 SELECT TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(TO_DATE('1997-05','YYYY-MM'),ROWNUM-1),'YYYY-MM') rowid1, 
              TRIM(TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(TO_DATE('1997-05','YYYY-MM'),ROWNUM-1),'month')) as n1
        FROM DUAL CONNECT BY ROWNUM<=months_between (to_date('1998-02', 'yyyy-mm'),to_date('1997-05', 'yyyy-mm'))+1
```

вот [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1009276/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%BE%D1%82-%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8-%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%82-%D0%B2-%D0%91%D0%94) говорится что

> Без явного указания сортировки с order by, порядок вывода строк
> произволен

но я явно не задаю  order by

Comment: Почемы вы повторяете этот [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1387888/217579). У вас остались какие-то доп.вопросы? Если да, то какие?

Comment: Конечно остались вопросы, я их написал в вопросе, ссылка ведущая к закрытию вопроса как дубля не отвечает на них.

Comment: Не совсем понятно, какой вопрос у вас остался. Вы не согласны с цитатой, которую вы же и привели в текущем вопросе, или она вам непонятна?  Сама цитата: _Без явного указания сортировки с order by, порядок вывода строк произволен_. Ваша фраза: _но я явно не задаю order by_. Вроде бы вернувшись к цитате выше следует: _порядок вывода строк произволен_. Так а что осталось непонятным или неотвеченым?

Comment: Пример моего запроса ВСЕГДА выводит в отсортированном виде даты без явного указания order by, вы утверждаете что "Без явного указания сортировки с order by, порядок вывода строк произволен", это противоречие. Поэтому я и спрашиваю надо ли принудительно делать сортировку или в этом примере нет нужды в этом действии и он будет всегда выводить в отсортированном виде?

Comment: Противоречия нет. Просто:  _ВСЕГДА выводит в отсортированном виде даты_, это ваше заблуждение. Даже если вы 1000000 раз попробуете и результат будет выглядеть отсортированым, то это не значит, что на 1000001 раз он будет выглядеть так-же, только из-за того, что разработчики Oracle что-то изменят во "внутренностях" БД. Приведённая цитата - это аксиома, т.е. она не нуждается в доказательстве. Поэтому, _надо ли принудительно делать сортировку или в этом примере нет нужды в этом действии_, да обязательно надо, в противном случае сортировка результата _не гарантированна_.